# Performing Batch Geoprocessing in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: geoprocessing, batch, arcgis-pro

I have been looking around in order to add multiple files instead of 1 at a time. I currently have about 55 files that I need to keep as separate layers.

ArcGIS 10.x had the option where you can right click a toolbox and choose Batch, but that's not the case (as far as I know) in ArcGIS pro.

Is there a way for me to use the tool for multiple files in ArcGIS pro, or it's only done through python or ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to use the Batch mode for geoprocessing tools in Pro. You would need to use Python (anoter less attractive option is ModelBuilder), which I recommend using even in ArcGIS Desktop (Batch mode sometimes is hard to control).

Comment: Thank you for that. I have been playing with ModelBuilder for the time being since I'm not familiar at all with arcpy. Even with that I have to manually attach each file to its own toolbox, or the output goes under one layer. Very annoying, but I guess Python is the way to go.

Comment: @Leb, I know what you mean. I've abandoned MB for about 2 years ago and don't regret. Life became so much better with arcpy :) to iterate your files will be just 3-4 lines of code. It is easier to learn how to do this than how to connect all those boxes in MB! :D

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Pro added [Batch Processing](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/batch-geoprocessing.htm) at version 2.2